# Cambiar un comportamiento que se está realizando cuando el puntero está encima de un elemento

Tags: javascript, sintaxis

Estoy aprendiendo *HTML*, *CSS* y ahora *JavaScript*... pero aun soy novato; mi problema es el siguiente:

Tengo un blog, la plantilla que tengo tiene una parte de JavaScript que muestra el título de las entradas únicamente cuándo el puntero esta encima de la misma, lo que quiero es que siempre sea visible el título o cuando esté al *focus*.

Aquí el código:

```
 // JavaScript Document
 function rm(id) {
   var p = document.getElementById(id);
   imgtag = "";
   img = p.getElementsByTagName("img");
   if (img.length >= 1) imgtag = '<img src="' + img[0].src + '" />';
   else imgtag = '';
   p.innerHTML = imgtag + '<div class="itemCaption"><div class="capContent"><h3 class="post-title entry-title" 
   itemprop="name"><a href="' + y + '">' + x + '</a></h3><a class="capPreview image-modal" href="' + y + '">Read More</a></div></div>'
 }
```

De ante mano les doy las gracias quien me pueda ayudar...

Comment: Podrias compartir tu blog para ver el comportamiento que tiene y darte una posible solucion, puedes solucionarlo de muchas maneras incluso se me ocurre con css

Comment: Si Amigo agradeciera tu ayuda de verdad aquí está: www.sechip.club @NikolaTesla

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Viendo tu código lo que haces es mostrar el contenido cuando haces `:hover` y estas trabajando con **pseudo elementos** lo cual visiblemente esta genial! te dejo un enlace para que aprendas más sobre  **pseudo elementos** [PseudoElementos en CSS](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gF7cJ34apTw)

Ve a tus estilos y al elemento que tiene la clase **.capContent** cambia la propiedad `opacity:0` a `opacity:1` esto deberia de mostrar siempre el titulo de tus entradas, pruébalo y me dices que paso.

Comment: Amigo realmente eres un genio, resolviste el problema de una forma que no había pensado, te agradezco mucho... de igual manera por el video. Gustoso me podrías enviar un e-mail por mi Blog para tener tu contacto para algún trabajó con su debida recompensa claro está por tu trabajo. Gracias @NikolaTesla